# How to save a many-to-many in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship that is not being saved by rails when created nor edited. I used checkbox control in order to get the many-to-many relation.

Basically when the user is creating the "Shop" it will have the checkboxes of the categories that shop belongs to (restaurant, burguer place, pizza makers). So the user will hit the checkboxes to select these categories.

I don't receive any errors and the operation is completed. The Shop is created but the relation is not saved on the database.

If I try to edit this shop, the relations are not there.

this is my models:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locale
  has_many :shop_categorizations
  has_many :shops_categories, through: :shop_categorizations
  has_many :shop_hours
  has_attached_file :image, :default_url => "/assets/default_image.png", :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/s3_credentials.yml"),
      :path => ":style/shop/:id",
      :url => ":s3_domain_url"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end


class ShopsCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shop_categorizations
  has_many :shops, through: :shop_categorizations
end


class ShopCategorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :shops_category
end
```

This is my controller that handles my code:

```
   class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shop, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @shop = Shop.new
  end

def create
    @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shop, notice: 'Shop was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shop }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def shop_params
      params.require(:shop).permit(:company_name, :fantasy_name, :cnpj, :locale_id, :street_name, :number, :neighborwood, :complement, :login, :password, :phone1, :phone2, :flag_open, :flag_card, :flag_delivery, :price_delivery, :image)
    end
```

My simple_form is prepared for it like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@shop) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :company_name %>
    <%= f.input :fantasy_name %>
    <%= f.input :cnpj %>
    <%= f.association :locale, :label_method => :city %>
    <br>
    <%= f.association :shops_categories, as: :check_boxes, :label_method => :name, :input_html => { :class => 'check'} %>
    <br>
    <%= f.input :street_name %>
    <%= f.input :number %>
    <%= f.input :neighborwood %>
    <%= f.input :complement %>
    <%= f.input :login %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :phone1 %>
    <%= f.input :phone2 %>
    <%= f.input :flag_open %>
    <%= f.input :flag_card %>
    <%= f.input :flag_delivery %>
    <%= f.input :price_delivery %>

    <%= f.input :image, as: :file %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I can't see any `shop_categories`, or `category_id` or anything that has to do with the categorization in your permitted params for shop.

Comment: we tried shop_categories and didn't work. For 'category_id' did you mean the table shopsCategory?

Comment: With a many-to-many relation, you would need a join table

Comment: Add `shop_category_ids` to the strong params list in the controller.

Comment: Can you list the output of params and shop params.  As the others have mentioned it looks like your shop_params method is not allowing the ids to come through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so like Alex mentioned in his comment, your `shop_params` should be as follow:

```
def shop_params
  params.require(:shop).permit(:company_name, :fantasy_name, :cnpj, :locale_id, :street_name, :number, :neighborwood, :complement, :login, :password, :phone1, :phone2, :flag_open, :flag_card, :flag_delivery, :price_delivery, :image, shops_category_ids: [])
end
```

Notice that the new addition, `shops_category_ids` is an array, to allow the array of `ids` coming from your

```
<%= f.association :shops_categories, as: :check_boxes, :label_method => :name, :input_html => { :class => 'check'} %>
```

in the form.